# spring integratoin ftp how to send files to different sub-folders

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I've managed to send all local files to the target ftp server folder with following config:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = FtpDef.FTP_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
public MessageHandler handler() {
    FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(
            // only one path can be set here 
            new LiteralExpression("/path/on/ftp/"));
    return handler;
}
```

now I need each file saved in a directory structure as the local.

e.g.

```
/base/a/a.txt  =>  /path/on/ftp/a/a.txt
/base/a/aa.txt  =>  /path/on/ftp/a/aa.txt

/base/b/b.txt  =>  /path/on/ftp/b/b.txt
/base/b/bb.txt  =>  /path/on/ftp/b/bb.txt
```

how can I accomplish that, I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> new LiteralExpression("/path/on/ftp/")

Don't use a `LiteralExpression`, which is, er... literal.

Instead, use:

```
new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(rdExpression)
```

Where `rdExpression` is something like...

```
"'/path/on/ftp/' + payload.absolutePath"
```

Comment: hi @Garry, I 've try to use payload.absolutePath,but I got ioexception which say that can not write to the path . Server replied with: 553 /base/b/b.txt.writing: No such file or directory.

Comment: now I've solved the path issue, what I need is the java config version of 'auto-create-directory' , I need to set it to true !but I don't know how...

Comment: `handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true)` - see [the javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/integration/ftp/outbound/FtpMessageHandler.html).